# Post from form submit is empty if input values from jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form where values may be given manually, or from a a predefined set from a dropdown.
When the dropdown is used. The values are filled with $.val(). When the from is submitted, the post has no parameters.
My HTML for the form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="/android/test/connection/form/" method="post">
    <div class="control-group has-feedback">
        <label for="name" class="control-label">Servernaam</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" disabled="disabled" id="name" name="name" value="" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="ipAddress-row" class="control-group error">
            <label for="ipAddress" class="control-label">IP adres</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" id="ipAddress" name="ipAddress" value="" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="tcpPort-row" class="control-group error">
            <label for="tcpPort" class="control-label">Poort</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" id="tcpPort" name="tcpPort" value="" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                <button type="reset" class="btn">Reset</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

and the dropdown

```
<div id="serverDropdown" class="offset1 btn-group">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <span>Known Servers</span>
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li role="presentation">
            <a role="menuitem" href="#" tabindex="-1">Server 1</a>
            <input type="hidden" name="ipAddress" value="127.0.0.1" />
            <input type="hidden" name="tcpPort" value="8600" />
            <input type="hidden" name="protocol" value="2" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And the javascript for filling the input:

```
$('#serverDropdown ul li a').click(function() {
    var item, inputs;
    removeErrors();
    item = $(this).parent();
    $('#name').val($(this).text());
    $('#ipAddress').val($(item).find('input[name=ipAddress]').val());
    $('#tcpPort').val($(item).find('input[name=tcpPort]').val());
    $('#protocol').val($(item).find('input[name=protocol]').val());
});
```

Comment: Why are you duplicating things?

Comment: Given it is a `click` on a link: `#serverDropdown ul li a`, you want to prevent the link to be followed using either `return false;` at the end or add the `ev` parameter to the function and doing `ev.preventDefault()`.

Comment: Can you set up a fiddle

Comment: Remove your anchor tag form li.

Comment: The click fills the data from the selected option into the form. Catching the event prevents the dropdown form closing. It's a bootstrap dropdown.  The values are visible on the screen,  but the problem is when the submit button is clicked: the form is posted to the server but the parameters ipAddress, and tcpPort that should be in the request, are not.